# Ubercart- Assign new role on expiry

Tags: rules, ubercart, users

I am granting users specific a role on purchase of some product( using ubercart). In doing so I have added a rule to take away their initial role(so that they do not have 2 roles and confuse the content access permissions). When the role expires, I want to grant the use back his original role. I am trying to use rules to do this. However, I am unsure on what action to call this rule. 
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "*I am unsure on what **action** to call this rule*" is your remaining issue, and that by using the rules module you are already close.

However, when talking about Rules and its Event-Condition-Action concept, your issue is about what **Event** to use. With that in mind, I would try to use the Rules Scheduler submodule of Rules, to schedule the rule to be executed at the moment of the purchase already.

Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using Ubercart Roles.

In Ubercart Role there is an option to send the notification to that user whose role is expired. You can trigger a rule on that event or you can define a role expiration event if you wish to tie it to a discrete event rather than the sending of an email.

I have found a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1820306) for [Role Expire](http://drupal.org/project/role_expire) which creates a Rules event upon role expiration that you might use as a model.

First you need to create a rule, then a simple action to assign a role (Add user role action) to the `expiration:user`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I did it almost exactly like that, however I wanted the event to be triggered exactly when the role expires - whereas now it is triggered "x" days before the expiry and only when the notification is sent to user(in case of the email expiry trigger).

Comment: Also, I am not using the Role Expire module but the built in expiry system that comes within UberCart.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is you can handled by drupal rules.